# Discord API - Invalid OAuth2 Access Token when trying to join a user to a server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently working on a Discord bot using Node.js and the Discord API. My goal is to join a user to a server using the guilds.join scope.

This is my code to get the identiy of the user and let him join a guild:

```js
  private async joinUserDiscordServer(accessData: any) {
    console.log(accessData) // #1

    const data = {
      access_token: `Bearer ${accessData.access_token}`,
    };
    const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN}`, setContentType: 'application/json' },
    };

    try {
      const userInfo = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.get('https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessData.access_token}` } })
      );

      console.log(userInfo.dta); // #2
      
      const result = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.put(`https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/${process.env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID}/members/${userInfo.data.id}`, data, options)
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e); // #3
      throw new HttpException(e, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }
```

#1 I get the following data:

```
{
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  expires_in: 604800,
  refresh_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  scope: 'email guilds guilds.join identify'
}
```

#2 I get the following data:

```
{
    id: 'xxxxxxxx',
    username: 'xxxxxxxx',
    avatar: 'xxxxxxxx',
    discriminator: '0',
    public_flags: 0,
    premium_type: 2,
    flags: 0,
    banner: 'xxxxxxxx',
    accent_color: 72262,
    global_name: 'xxxxxxxx',
    avatar_decoration_data: null,
    banner_color: '#011a46',
    mfa_enabled: true,
    locale: 'de',
    email: 'xxxxxxxx',
    verified: true
}
```

#3 I get the following Error Message:
`data: { message: 'Invalid OAuth2 access token', code: 50025 }`

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- The bot is already present on the server.
- Only one application is being used for both obtaining the access token and attempting to join the guild.
- The bot has the appropriate permissions (Incorrect permissions lead to a different error).
- The bot token provided is accurate (An incorrect token results in a different error).

---

**So what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I need the authorization for my webpage. But in the same moment, they should be added to the discord server (auth url: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1195419357472374866&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fauth%2Fverify%2Fredirect&scope=identify+guilds.join)

Comment: The only time I have seen this question asked is when someone has attempted to use OAuth guild joining to sell "guild members". What is your intended usage for it?

Comment: I'm creating this page for a Lan Party, the participants register on a tool and should be automatically added to the discord server. ;) So no scam or so ^^